# Make a tweet from Java application

Tags: java, twitter

I need help to post a tweet from an Java application, I already made some work, reagarding the authorization part.

I made a connection to the Twitter authorization and been routed to the page on Twitter where you grant the application access to Twitter.

But now I want to make a connection and to be able to post a tweet from my user account. How do I go about this?

I've looked in to some guide's but they all give me different answers and are a bit confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use Twitter Java libraries, such as [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) ?

Comment: I am creating this connection to Twitter from ordinary Java for now, but will later on create it for a Android 1.5 application, and from what I coulde see Twitter4J is only working on Android 2.1 and up. :(

Comment: Did you tried with other libraries, such as http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/ ?

Comment: And even Twitter4j is open source so you can see how they did it if you are stuck.